# Winning a game with increasing difficulty. Probability, Expected Values and Convergent Sums.

Tags: probability

Let us assume a game. This game consists of several rounds. The player is presented  with one round at a time and is moved to the next round if and only if he does not 'win' the previous round. The probability of winning the $n$th round is described by the function $P(n) = \frac{1}{2^n}$. A player in this game keeps playing until he has won 1 game.

Let us compute the probability that the player has won after n rounds.

As stated before the probability of having won on any game n can be described by the function $P(n) = \frac{1}{2^n}$, meaning the odds of winning rounds 1,2,3 and 4 are $\frac12, \frac14,\frac18,$and $\frac1{16}$ respectively. Now the probability of ending a game on any round n is equal to the product of the probability of winning this round and the probability of not winning all previous rounds.

$$P(\mathrm{Win\ on\ game \ n} ) = P(\mathrm{Win\ game \ n} ) + P(\mathrm{Dont \ win\ on\ games \ less \ than \ n} )$$

In the case of this game this can be expressed as
 $$P(\mathrm{Win\ on\ game \ n} ) = \frac{1}{2^n} + P(\mathrm{Dont \ win\ on\ games \ less \ than \ n} )$$ 
where 
$$ P(\mathrm{Dont \ win\ on\ games \ less \ than \ n} ) = P(\mathrm{Dont \ win\ on\ games \ less \ than \ n - 1} )  - P(\mathrm{Win\ on\ game \ n} )$$ 
 We could then sum $P(\mathrm{Win\ on\ game \ n} ) $ for all n in a range to find the probability of wining after a certain number of games
$$\sum^n_{i=0} P(\mathrm{Win\ on\ game \ i} )$$
Now one would assume that this sums as most probability does would approach 1 as n approaches infinity. This is intuitive, but is it true?
$$\sum^{\infty}_{i=0} P(\mathrm{Win\ on\ game \ i} ) = 1$$
After some some bashing away with a computer the sum seems to stop going up around $P = 0.7112$, have I not computed far enough or does the sum converge before 1? Does this mean a sizable chunk of our game players will play to infinity?

Bonus: What is the expected value for number of turns required to end the game?

Comment: The probability of not winning of the first $n$ round is $\prod_{i=1}^n \frac {2^i-1} {2^i}$. The numerator is given by https://oeis.org/A048651 and the decimal expansion of the limit is given by https://oeis.org/A048651 So the probability indeed converge to a number less than 1, and thus it is possible for the players to play for infinity many rounds with that probability and the expectation will not converge.

Comment: You should replace some + signs with $\cdot$s.